# Pyspark: Joining 2 dataframes by ID & Closest date backwards

Tags: python, sql, join, pyspark

I'm having the world of issues performing a rolling join of two dataframes in pyspark (and python in general). I am looking to join two pyspark dataframes together by their ID & closest date backwards (meaning the date in the second dataframe cannot be greater than the one in the first)

Table_1:

[image: +-----+------------+-------+ | ID | Date | Value | +-----+------------+-------+ | A1 | 01-15-2020 | 5 | | A2 | 01-20-2020 | 10 | | A3 | 02-21-2020 | 12 | | A1 | 02-21-2020 | 6 | +-----+------------+-------+]

Table_2:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image: ID Date Value Value 2 A1 01-15-2020 5 5 A2 01-20-2020 10 12 A3 02-21-2020 12 14 A1 01-21-2020 6 3]

In essence, I understand an SQL Query can do the trick where I can do spark.sql("query") So anything else. I've tried several things which aren't working in a spark context. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([('A1','1/15/2020',5),
                           ('A2','1/20/2020',10), 
                           ('A3','2/21/2020',12),
                           ('A1','1/21/2020',6)],
                           ['ID1','Date1','Value1'])

df2=spark.createDataFrame([('A1','1/10/2020',1),
                           ('A1','1/12/2020',5),
                           ('A1','1/16/2020',3),
                           ('A2','1/25/2020',20),
                           ('A2','1/1/2020',12),
                           ('A3','1/31/2020',14),
                           ('A3','1/30/2020',12)],['ID2','Date2','Value2'])

df2=df1.join(df2,df1.ID1==df2.ID2) \
    .withColumn("distance",datediff(to_date(df1.Date1,'MM/dd/yyyy'),\
     to_date(df2.Date2,'MM/dd/yyyy'))).filter("distance>0")

df2.groupBy(df2.ID1,df2.Date1,df2.Value1)\
   .agg(min(df2.distance).alias('distance')).join(df2, ['ID1','Date1','distance'])\
   .select(df2.ID1,df2.Date1,df2.Value1,df2.Value2).orderBy('ID1','Date1').show()
```

Comment: I like the idea, but could you please explain what you are doing in your code?

Comment: Generally speaking : it's doing a N-N comparison of all the dates with the same ID, which is then having a N^2 complexity. It computes the distance for each pair, and keep the lower distance's ones. If both dataframes are big (many times the same ID) it could lead to some strong performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my trial.

First, I determine the `Date_2` which met your condition. After that, join the second dataframe again and get the `Value_2`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, unix_timestamp, max

df3 = df1.withColumn('newId', monotonically_increasing_id()) \
  .join(df2, 'ID', 'left') \
  .where(unix_timestamp('Date', 'M/dd/yy') >= unix_timestamp('Date_2', 'M/dd/yy')) \
  .groupBy(*df1.columns, 'newId') \
  .agg(max('Date_2').alias('Date_2'))
df3.orderBy('newId').show(20, False)    

+---+-------+-----+-----+-------+
|ID |Date   |Value|newId|Date_2 |
+---+-------+-----+-----+-------+
|A1 |1/15/20|5    |0    |1/12/20|
|A2 |1/20/20|10   |1    |1/11/20|
|A3 |2/21/20|12   |2    |1/31/20|
|A1 |1/21/20|6    |3    |1/16/20|
+---+-------+-----+-----+-------+

df3.join(df2, ['ID', 'Date_2'], 'left') \
  .orderBy('newId') \
  .drop('Date_2', 'newId') \
  .show(20, False)

+---+-------+-----+-------+
|ID |Date   |Value|Value_2|
+---+-------+-----+-------+
|A1 |1/15/20|5    |5      |
|A2 |1/20/20|10   |12     |
|A3 |2/21/20|12   |14     |
|A1 |1/21/20|6    |3      |
+---+-------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to solve this problem using Window.
You need to join both datasets using id and date(>=), then you need to know how many days of difference you have in order to filter what you need using dense_rank to just get closest date.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, datediff, dense_rank
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from datetime import date

df1 = (
  spark
  .createDataFrame(
    [
      ("A1",date(2020, 1, 15), 5),
      ("A2",date(2020, 1, 20), 10),
      ("A3",date(2020, 2, 21), 12),
      ("A1",date(2020, 1, 21), 6),
    ],
    ["id_1","date_1","value_1"]
  )
)

df2 = (
  spark
  .createDataFrame(
    [
      ("A1",date(2020, 1, 10), 1),
      ("A1",date(2020, 1, 12), 5),
      ("A1",date(2020, 1, 16), 3),
      ("A2",date(2020, 1, 25), 20),
      ("A2",date(2020, 1, 1), 12),
      ("A3",date(2020, 1, 31), 14),
      ("A3",date(2020, 1, 30), 12)
    ],
    ["id_2","date_2","value_2"]
  )
)

winSpec = Window.partitionBy("value_1").orderBy("date_difference")

df3 = (
  df1
  .join(df2, [df1.id_1==df2.id_2,df1.date_1>=df2.date_2])
  .withColumn("date_difference", datediff("date_1","date_2"))
  .withColumn("dr", dense_rank().over(winSpec))
  .where("dr=1")
  .select(
    col("id_1").alias("id"),
    col("date_1").alias("date"),
    col("value_1"),
    col("value_2")
  )
)

+---+----------+-------+-------+
|id |date      |value_1|value_2|
+---+----------+-------+-------+
|A1 |2020-01-21|6      |3      |
|A1 |2020-01-15|5      |5      |
|A2 |2020-01-20|10     |12     |
|A3 |2020-02-21|12     |14     |
+---+----------+-------+-------+
```